# Bukkit custom item consuming

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

In my new Bukkit project, I need to create custom edible Items with a plugin, not a mod.

I want to create new kinds of food, like honey or muffins. I know how to implement the crafting recipe, but not how to detect if the item is consumed.

What can I do in order to detect the consumption of an Item and proc it's effects in the same fashion as a normal food from Minecraft?

Comment: To make your items consumeable, try using e.g. a porkchop with a custom meta data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to make a "Munching" animation with every Item that's not consumable (IE potions and food).
Nevertheless, you can use the following events when a player interacts and when a player eats/drinks something, as follows:

---

**PlayerInteractEvent**

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    //Event called when a player interacts with something, AKA right click or left click
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack hand = player.getItemInHand();
    if(/**Hand is honey**/) //DOSOMETHING
}
```

**PlayerItemConsumeEvent**

```
@EventHandler
public void onConsume(PlayerItemConsumeEvent e {
    ItemStack consumed = e.getItem();
    Player consumer = e.getPlayer();
    if (/*Consumed is Honey*/) //DoSomething
}
```

---

From there you can use Saturation to add food bars to your player, and manipulate the ItemStack to remove one from it.